# Live data usage monitoring in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I coded a simple Cordova program for my colleagues that streams a video (which is in my pc connected to a work place lan) and all my colleagues are connected to WIFI (work place lan) which made it easy to view my pc's content. The program worked good. I used [Polyvi Xface Traffic Monitor](https://github.com/polyvi/xface-extension-trafficstats) plugin to get the data usage.

```
...
function checkStats(){
xFace.TrafficStats.getWifiTraffic(success, fail);
}
...
function success(result) {
        data = document.querySelector("#dataUsage");
        data.innerHTML = result + "Kb";
    }

    function fail(error) {
        data = document.querySelector("#dataUsage");
        data.innerHTML = error;
    }
```

This works great if i call checkStats() function (usually from a button's onClick). But how to get the data usage real time with out clicking the button everytime.

I just want to know, Is there anyway to do it?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: call the checkStats on the deviceready event

Comment: I already did that, but it shows 0 Kb ( data.innerHTML) and it's not real time, it stays static.

Comment: Hello Ranjith, I tried using this in my app but for some reason it does not work: I always get 0Kb as a consumption... may I ask you what your config is and whether it worked please? I try this code in a hybrid (IONIC) app on Android...

Comment: Hi @hartmut. It actually did worked for me. Did you tried calling the function (in my case CheckStats() function) on a OnClick event? and checked the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it alas,

I used `window.setInterval(checkStats, 5);`in deviceready,

and it works perfect.